# Игра с мячом и платформой на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, разработка-игр, pygame

Есть игра, где мяч отскакивает от платформы и летит в обратном направлении. 
Я хочу сделать такую же, но не получается сделать отталкивание от платформы.

Вот мой код:

```
import pygame
import sys

size = width, height = 800, 600
black = 0, 0, 0


def main():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    ball_image = pygame.image.load("basketball.png")
    ball_rect = ball_image.get_rect()
    ball_rect.x = 101
    ball_rect.y = 101
    game_over = False
    dx = 2
    dy = 2
    platform_x = 325
    platform_y = 500
    move_right = False
    move_left = False

    while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (platform_x, platform_y, 150, 20))
        screen.blit(ball_image, ball_rect)
        ball_rect.x += dx
        ball_rect.y += dy
        #ball_rectan_x = ball_rect.x
        #ball_rectan_y = ball_rect.y
        #ball_rectan_x = ball_rectan_x + 150
        #ball_rectan_y= ball_rectan_y + 150
        if ball_rect.y < 0 or ball_rect.y > 500 and ball_rect.x > platform_x and ball_rect.x < platform_x + 150:
            dy *= -1
        if ball_rect.x < 0 or ball_rect.y > 500 and ball_rect.x > platform_x and ball_rect.x < platform_x + 150:
            dx *= -1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if chr(event.key) == 'd':
                move_right = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if chr(event.key) == 'd':
                move_right = False
        if move_right:
            platform_x += 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if chr(event.key) == 'a':
                move_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if chr(event.key) == 'a':
                move_left = False
        if move_left:
            platform_x -= 1
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А что не так с кодом?

Comment: но не получается сделать отталкивание от платформы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить немного вот эти два условия на нижеследующее:

```
if  (ball_rect.y < 0 or ball_rect.y > height) or (ball_rect.y + ball_rect.h > platform_y and ball_rect.x > platform_x and ball_rect.x < platform_x + platform_width):
    dy *= -1
if  (ball_rect.x < 0 or ball_rect.x > width) or (ball_rect.x + ball_rect.w > platform_x and ball_rect.y > platform_y and ball_rect.y < platform_y + platform_height):           
    dx *= -1
```

А вообще советую написать небольшую функцию для проверки столкновений наподобие:

```
def BallCollision(sa,sb):
    if   (int(sa.pos.dx + sa.size.dx/2) > sb.pos.dx and int(sa.pos.dx + sa.size.dx/2) < (sb.pos.dx+sb.size.dx)):
        sa.mirrory()
    elif (int(sa.pos.dy + sa.size.dy/2) > sb.pos.dy and int(sa.pos.dy + sa.size.dy/2) < (sb.pos.dy+sb.size.dx)):
        sa.mirrorx()
```

А все внутриигровые объекты типа мяча и доски оформить как классы (ООП). Так ими намного удобнее оперировать. И ошибок меньше будете допускать.

Comment: Так я уже делал, не получается, он отскакивает гораздо раньше чем касается

Comment: Ну это же большой прогресс по сравнению с тем что у Вас не отражался вообще ))) Ладно, ловите патч №2 : (внес исправления в код -- см. мой ответ выше).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame
import sys

size = width, height = 800, 600
black = 0, 0, 0

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
# !!!
    ball_image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")                 # ! ball.png
    ball_rect = ball_image.get_rect()
    ball_rect.x = 101
    ball_rect.y = 101
    game_over = False
    dx = 2
    dy = 2
    platform_x = 325
    platform_y = 500
    move_right = False
    move_left = False

    while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
        screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (platform_x, platform_y, 150, 20))
        screen.blit(ball_image, ball_rect)
        ball_rect.x += dx
        ball_rect.y += dy
        #ball_rectan_x = ball_rect.x
        #ball_rectan_y = ball_rect.y
        #ball_rectan_x = ball_rectan_x + 150
        #ball_rectan_y= ball_rectan_y + 150
# !!!                                       vvv <---- 500
        if ball_rect.y < 0 or ball_rect.y > 480 \
            and ball_rect.x > platform_x \
            and ball_rect.x < platform_x + 150:
            dy *= -1

#        if ball_rect.x < 0 or ball_rect.y > 480 and ball_rect.x > platform_x and ball_rect.x < platform_x + 150:
# !!!                         vvvvvvvvvvV   vvv <-------------- !!!
        if ball_rect.x < 0 or ball_rect.x > 780: 
            dx *= -1
            
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if chr(event.key) == 'd':
                move_right = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if chr(event.key) == 'd':
                move_right = False
        if move_right:
# !!!                     2
            platform_x += 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if chr(event.key) == 'a':
                move_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if chr(event.key) == 'a':
                move_left = False
        if move_left:
# !!!                     2
            platform_x -= 2
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]